# Kotlin: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException during converting DispatchTask to string

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

We have released our first Kotlin pieces into production and we are getting crashes with this stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.ReflectionFactory.renderLambdaToString(ReflectionFactory.java:47)
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.Reflection.renderLambdaToString(Reflection.java:80)
       at kotlin.jvm.internal.Lambda.toString(Lambda.kt:22)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedContinuation.toString(CoroutineDispatcher.kt:192)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchTask.toString(CoroutineDispatcher.kt:124)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Google show us this is happening in 100 % on Android 5. Crashlytics/Fabric shows also two crashes from Android 4.4. No crashes from newer Android versions.

I have no idea how to prevent this crash or how to replicate it.

Current version:

- org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.16

Comment: Please post your loop code.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that. Do you mean a code with cycle/loop that was written in Kotlin?

Comment: First, pull the app.  Once you solve the crashes, then release to production.  Second.  reproduce the error preferably in debug, but use logcat and other tools with a production build (in house).  If it happens 100%, then I don't understand what you mean by "no idea how to ... replicate"

Comment: Do you use proguard or something similar? It looks as if superinterfaces of lambdas were erased by a post-processing tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug in Kotlin reflection. Meanwhile, I'd suggest to upgrade to the latest version of `kotlinx.coroutines` library (you can find what is the latest version [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/README.md)). Since version 0.17 `DispatchTask.toString` does not try to covert lambda to string anymore. It's `toString` implementation is actually more useful now and has more relevant information for debugging purposes.

Comment: Thanks! Will try 0.18 :-)